# In Ruby, how do I assign a value to a class instance

Tags: ruby, class, initialization

I want to create a class instance that has a value such that I can do something like `puts a = Example.new(1)` where `a`'s value is specified in `initialize`.
I expect that this is a simple problem since all predefined Ruby classes allow this, but I'm unable to figure out how to do it for my classes.

Comment: `puts a = Example.new(1)` doesn't make sense. You're printing the result of an assignment which is always nil. Think of it as `puts (a = Example.new(1))` Do you mean `puts Example.new(1)`

Comment: @nita No, the *return value* of puts is nil, but `puts(a = 1); a # => 1` and is perfectly valid.

Comment: @nlta the result of an assignment is the assigned value.

Comment: You could define a _getter_ via `attr_reader :a`, assign the corresponding instance variable `@a` in `initialize` and print it via `puts Example.new(1).a`

Comment: @ArkanasStacker Could you explain your question a bit better? Are you looking to define what is printed for an instance during `puts`? You have to implement `def to_s` in your class for this.

Comment: You need to correct your terminology. You can only assign values to variables, but a class instance is not a variable. I expect you want to know how can you assign a value to an instance variable for a given class instance. As you refer to `a = Example.new(1)` I assume you have something like `class Example; def initialize(a); @a = a; end; end`. Then `inst = Example.new(1) #= #<Example:0x00007f89341179b0 @a=1>`. Notice that `inst` holds the instance and the current value of the instance variable `@a` is seen to be `1`. You can change that with `inst.instance_variable_set('@a', 2) #=> 2`...

Comment: ...To confirm `@a`'s current value we can write `inst.instance_variable_get('@a') #=> 2`. See [Object#instance_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) and [Object#instance_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get). These methods are not needed if, as @Stefan mentions, *setter* and *getter* methods have been defined using [Module#attr_accessor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### Class#new and Return Values

Your example doesn't quite work because Ruby treats Class#new as a special case, and is expected to invoke the #initialize method and return an object. If it didn't, calling #new on a class would surprise a lot of people by returning the last evaluation of the initializer from your class, or from Object#new if it's otherwise undefined for your class. In either case, this would violate the principle of least surprise.

However, you can do what you want pretty easily by simply creating an accessor method and then chaining off of Example#new. For example, in Ruby 3.1.0:

```rb
class Example
  attr_reader :int
  def initialize(int) = (@int = int)
end

# prints `1` to STDOUT and assigns the value to *a*,
# but returns nil because you're using Kernel#puts
# which always returns nil
puts a = Example.new(1).int

# shows that the local variable *a* is set to the value
# returned by the Example#int accessor for the class'
# @int instance variable
a
#=> 1
```

To avoid the confusion of having a nil return value (even though this is expected with [Kernel#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts), just change your puts statement to use [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) instead:

```rb
p a = Example.new(2).int
#=> 2
```

### Refactoring the Example Class for Older Rubies

If you're using an older Ruby than 3.0, you can't use an [endless method](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.0.html#endless-method-definition) or the [improved handling](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.1.html#inside-endless-method-definitions-method-calls-without-parenthesis-are-allowed) for them in Ruby 3.1. The only difference is that rather than an inline method, you need to specify it with the standard def...end syntax, e.g.:

```rb
class Example
  attr_reader :int
  def initialize(int)
    @int = int
  end
end
```

Otherwise, the points above are valid as far back as any currently-supported Ruby version.

Comment: `new` is special by convention, you're free to write your own `new` method that returns whatever you want. That would be a terrible thing to do but you're free to do it.

Comment: A popular example is `Struct` which overrides [`::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Struct.html#method-c-new) to return a new custom anonymous class each time.

Comment: "Your example doesn't quite work because Ruby treats Class#new as a special case" – There is nothing special about `Class#new`. It is basically just `class Class; def new(...) obj = allocate; obj.__send__(:initialize, ...); obj end end`